# Question About Compact Space in Topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am really confused about below questions. Actually, I did some inferences but I am not sure. Thank you

(i) Show that T = {A ⊂ R | 1 ∉ A } ∪ {$\mathbb{R}$} is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and show that the space ($\mathbb{R}$, t) is a compact space according to this topology.

Thank you for now.

Comment: An open cover of $T$ must contain an open set $U$ such that $1\in U$, so…

Comment: I didn't exactly undestand what you mean...

Comment: You should add to your question what you have tried so far and where you're stuck at. Working exercises is a good way to learn mathematics and simply providing a full solution wouldn't help you. You need to (1) prove that $T$ is a topology; (2) prove that any open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ by sets in $T$ has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover for $\Bbb R$ in this topology. In particular there is an $U \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $1 \in U$.

By the **definition** of the topology $\mathcal{T}$ the **only** open set that contains $1$ is $\Bbb R$ itself. So $U = \Bbb R$ and so $\{U\}$ is a (very) finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}$. So the space is compact : every open cover has a finite subcover (always the same boring one in this trivial case).

Answer (score 0):

Let $T=\{A\subseteq\mathbb R:1\notin  A\}\cup \{\mathbb R\}$ be a topology on $\mathbb R$. First we show that it's indeed a topology.

(i) Observe that $\emptyset,\mathbb R \in T$ (because $1\notin \emptyset\implies \emptyset\in\{A\subseteq\mathbb R:1\notin  A\}$).
(ii) Let $\mathcal A=\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of open sets in $T$. Since $\forall i\in I$, $A_i\in T\implies 1\notin A_i\forall i\in I$.
Therefore we can state that $1\notin \underset{A_i\in\mathcal A}{\bigcup}A_i\implies \underset{A_i\in\mathcal A}{\bigcup}A_i\in T$.
(iii) If we now consider $A_1,A_2\in\mathcal A\implies 1\notin A_1,A_2\implies 1\notin A_1\cap A_2\implies A_1\cap A_2\in T$, hence $T$ defines a topology on $\mathbb R$.

Let $\mathcal F$ be a family of open sets that covers $\mathbb R$, then $1$ will be neccesairily in $\mathcal F$, so $\mathcal F$ must contain all the real line.
In other words, if $1\in \mathcal F$, then $\exists A\in\mathcal F:1\in A$, but the unique open set that contains the point $\{1\}$ is $\mathbb R\implies A=\mathbb R$. Since $\mathcal F$ was a generic family of open sets that covers $X=(\mathbb R,T)$, it follows that $X$ is compact because we can always find the open sub-cover $\{A\}$.

Comment: Thank you for instructive solutions. But I have really some essential information deficiencies about this topic. I would be very grateful if you could explain the final part.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer. Let me know... :-)